# web socket connection in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket

I have created a angular project in which my web socket connection is getting open after reloading the page otherwise it does not open. I want to start a socket as soon as user logs in and close the socket as it logs out.

Below is the socket service I created using `rxjs` web sockets not `socket.io` :

```
    SOCKET_URL: string = environment.webSocketEndpoint;
    ws: WebSocketSubject<any>;

    open() {
        this.ws = webSocket(`${this.SOCKET_URL}/?access_token=${this.auth.user()?.['accessToken']}&platform=web`);
    }
    emit(event: Object): void {
        this.ws.next(event);
    }

    events(): Observable<any> {
        if (this.ws === undefined ) {
            this.open();
        }

        return this.ws?.asObservable();
    }

    close() {
        this.ws.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

In `app.ts` on `nogOnit()` :

```
if(this.auth.user()){
this.socketService.open()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { WebSocketSubject, webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

ngOnInit() {
    this.WebSocket = webSocket(environment.webSoketBaseURL + '/websocket_path/');
    this.webSocket.asObservable().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
    });
}
```